# Problema al ejecutar Query JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jdbc, jpql

Al tratar de realizar la siguiente query:

```
SELECT a FROM Autor a WHERE a.id_autor LIKE :id_autor
```

Me arroja esta Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT a FROM Autor a WHERE a.id_autor LIKE :id_autor]. 
[28, 38] The state field path 'a.id_autor' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

Aqui dejo una foto de mis tablas y sus nombres

[image: Tablas]

Y aqui realizo la consulta

```
Autor autor = (Autor) em.createQuery(Constantes.OBTENER_AUTOR_POR_ID).setParameter("id_autor", id_autor).getSingleResult();
```

Y aqui añado mis entidades

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "autor")
public class Autor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_autor")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "alta")
    private Boolean alta;
```

Comment: Tu query no es válida. Usa algo como `"from Autor where id = :id_autor"`. Lo probé y [funciona sin problemas](https://ibb.co/xY59xM2).

Comment: [7, 7] The select expression is missing from the SELECT clause.
[18, 18] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.

Comment: Está raro, a mi me salió sin problema como te mostré en la imagen, debe ser algo con tu configuración de hibernate. Puedes simplificarte la vida con los métodos de em en algo tan simple como `Autor autor = em.find(Autor.class, 1);`

Comment: Pues la verdad todavía no he podido encontrar el error, muchas graicas por tu ayuda de igual manera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas usando query nativo? (es decir nativeQuery = true) porque si no estas usando query nativo, debes acceder al campo de la entidad Autor en la cláusula `where` con el nombre del atributo de clases (id):

```sql
SELECT a FROM Autor a WHERE **a.id** LIKE :id_autor
```

También asegúrate de que sean el mismo tipo de datos (el parámetro :id_autor y el campo del entity)